# Using a table as a header in Context

Tags: tables, header-footer, context

I want to define a table to use as a header in my Context document. This table shall contain different variables, like document title, document number, date, page x of yy, etc. I have defined the table below.

```
\setupTABLE[column][1][width=.45\textwidth]
\setupTABLE[column][2,3][width=.22\textwidth]
\setupTABLE[row][each][height=0.5cm]

\bTABLE
\bTR \bTD Project name \eTD \bTD[nc=2] Doc. no: 1897-APL-N-CA-0001 \eTD \eTR
\bTR \bTD Document title: \eTD \bTD[nc=2] Page 2 of 81 \eTD \eTR
\bTR \bTD[nr=2] Report name \eTD \bTD Client rev. no \eTD \bTD Date: 31.12.1982\eTD \eTR
\bTR \bTD C127-AU-1234-ABC \eTD \bTD \eTD \eTR
\eTABLE
```

I have tried to define it as a Setup, with the following

```
\startsetups[tableheader]
% insert table here
\stopsetups
```

and using:

```
\setupheadertexts[\setups{tableheader}][]
```

... without any luck.

The next step would be to replace some of the text in the table, with variable names which can be defined elsewhere.

Comment: Please create a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) illustrating the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing relevant lines with:

```
\setupheadertexts[\setups{tableheader}]
```

and

```
\bTABLE[split=no] % allow splitting over page boundaries
```

it should work then. You can also insert images into cells in your header table.

My compiler is LuaTeX from TeXLive package.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but an extended comment. The code that you posted works as expected for me; so create a minimal example that shows what is going wrong at your end.

Note, the `\showframe` is only for diagnostic purposes.

```
\startsetups[tableheader]
  \setupTABLE[column][1][width=.45\textwidth]
  \setupTABLE[column][2,3][width=.22\textwidth]
  \setupTABLE[row][each][height=0.5cm]

  \bTABLE
  \bTR \bTD Project name \eTD \bTD[nc=2] Doc. no: 1897-APL-N-CA-0001 \eTD \eTR
  \bTR \bTD Document title: \eTD \bTD[nc=2] Page 2 of 81 \eTD \eTR
  \bTR \bTD[nr=2] Report name \eTD \bTD Client rev. no \eTD \bTD Date: 31.12.1982\eTD \eTR
  \bTR \bTD C127-AU-1234-ABC \eTD \bTD \eTD \eTR
  \eTABLE
\stopsetups
\setupheadertexts[\setups{tableheader}][]

\setupbodyfont[12pt]
\setuplayout[header=5\lineheight]
\showframe

\starttext
\input ward

\stoptext
```

[image]