# Context - TABLE commands in body of document affecting TABLEs in header

Tags: header-footer, context, xtable

I am trying to use a TABLE as a header in Context (see [Using a table as a header in Context](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240249/using-a-table-as-a-header-in-context)). However, the \setupTABLEs and \bTABLE[head|foot]s commands in the body of the document affect the TABLE in the header. The snippet below illustrates the problem:

1. The TABLE in the header has a header row.
2. This header row has a yellow background.

Is this a bug? Or is there a way to "scope" the \setupTABLE \bTABLE[head|foot] commands to only affect a specific TABLE.

With reference to https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2015/083192.html, I have tried using \egroup and \sgroup. My \setupTABLEs are also already defined within the \bTABLE block.

```
\startsetups[header]
\bTABLE
    \bTR
        \bTD Header \eTD
    \eTR
\eTABLE
\stopsetups

\setupheadertexts[\setups{header}]

\starttext

\bTABLE[split=repeat, header=yes]
    \setupTABLE[r][first]
        [background=color,
        backgroundcolor=yellow]
    \bTABLEhead
        \bTR
            \bTH Header \eTH
        \eTR
    \eTABLEhead
    \bTABLEbody
        \dorecurse{100} {
        \bTR
            \bTD Body \eTD
        \eTR
        }
    \eTABLEbody
\eTABLE

\stoptext
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. This is a nice first question. You might want to change some s into b (like in sTABLE) above.

Comment: Fixed, thanks for the welcome and the corrections.

Comment: You can use different table environments in the document header and body (e.g. natural tables and xtables). A even better solution is to avoid using tables in the header and using `\framed` etc. to create the desired layout.

Comment: This should probably be another question. That said, I have tried both xtables and tabulate. (xtables example: https://gist.github.com/shasderias/ca4dffd6037ff7b50be2dbf8bd4d5682) and they don't appear to play well with being put in a header.

Comment: When you put xtables in other commands like a setups environment you have to replace `\startxtable ... \stopxtable` with `\startembeddedxtable ... \stopembeddedxtable`.

Comment: For completeness: Metafox's amendment allowed the table in the header to render correctly. However, you may encounter the error described in https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2015/083365.html if the TABLE in the document body spans multiple pages. In my case, a combination of one or more of the following was necessary to allow the document to render (correctly): 1) `\insidesplitfloatfalse`, 2) `[option=stretch]` in `\startembeddedxtable`, 3) `[offset=xpt]`, 4) `[split=no]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One workaround is to tell ConTeXt that the table in the header is a nested table. That way, ConTeXt will ignore the setups defined at the previous level. You can do this as follows:

```
\unprotect
\startsetups[header]
\tabl_ntb_next_level
\bTABLE
    \bTR
        \bTD Header \eTD
    \eTR
\eTABLE
\tabl_ntb_prev_level
\stopsetups
\protect
```

The `\unprotect` and `\protect` are needed because `\tabl_ntb_next_level` is an internal command.